# How to enable part of a code, specifically another event handler, in C# after clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, events, tcplistener

I have a scenario where I am connecting to server over TCP/IP protocol. This needs to be done after I click the "Connect to TCP/IP server" button on my Windows form. Upon clicking this button the status of the connection, either successful or failed, is displayed. This part I managed quite easily. What I need is that when the connection is successful, only then the program/code needs to start listening to the incomming messages from server and procede futher. I tested if I can get server messages without the button (i.e., when the form initializes it automatically connect to the server) and it worked fine. You will see in the code below that I am using reference commands to a third party software on the same PC which handles the incomming messages from the server. The reason for the third party software is simply beacuse I am using VisualStudio and C# to extend the capabilities of the software which is allowed by this software in their documentation. I will indeed be writing some of the variables to this third party software. This I am also fine with doing. Hence, the only problem I have is to only enable the listening of the incomming meassage from the server when the connect button is pressed and the connection is successful.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my code so far, but it does not work:
`

```
namespace Form1
{
    public partial class Main_Form: Form
    {
        private CogJob Job;
        private CogJobManager Job_manager;
        private CogJobIndependent Job_independent;

        String Received_string;
        bool State_of_connection = false;
        ICogIOTCPIP TCP_IP_server_device;
        
        public Main_HMI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Load application
            Job_manager = (CogJobManager)(CogSerializer.LoadObjectFromFile(@"Project"));

            // Initialize job variables
            Job = Job_manager.Job("Application");
            Job_independent = Job.OwnedIndependent;

            // Flush all job queues
            Job.ImageQueueFlush();
            Job_manager.UserQueueFlush();
            Job_manager.FailureQueueFlush();
            Job_independent.RealTimeQueueFlush();

            if (State_of_connection == true)
            {
                TCP_IP_server_device.MessageReceived += new     CogIOStreamMessageEventHandler(TCP_IP_server_device_MessageReceived);
            }
            
        }
        
        // Decode the message received from the TCP/IP server device
        private void TCP_IP_server_device_MessageReceived(object sender, CogIOStreamMessageEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Received_string = eventArgs.DecodedMessage.Substring(2, 9);
        }

        // Savely shutdown application job manager when the form is closed;
        private void Main_HMI_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Job_manager.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Connect_to_TCP_IP_server_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Job_manager.IOEnable = true;
            TCP_IP_server_device = Job_manager.StreamInput("PLC", 2000, true);

            if (TCP_IP_server_device == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection failed", "TCP/IP server device connection status");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection successful", "TCP/IP server device connection status");
                State_of_connection = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: what exactly "doesn't work".  Have you tried debugging?  What is happening differently than you expect/want?

Comment: Well, in my orginal code above I never receive the messages comming from the server. In other words the "State _of_connection" bool variable never changes to true so that each time I send a message from the server side it will procede in decoding it. What I want is I click the connect button once and after that the program should continiously wait for incomming messages without me having to click the connect button again.

Comment: why don't you add your event handler independently of State_of_connection? Is that not possible?

Comment: The problem with that is that the eventhandler for the incomming messages, "CogIOStreamMessageEventHandler", when it is initialized with the TCP/IP server device of null (i.e., its original value at form start up) it throws out an error. This is unfortunately how that event handler from the third part software works.

Comment: Within the third party software example they connect automatically to the server when starting up the form. Hence the TCP/IP server device of null is given a value other than null when actually connected to the server and the event handler "CogIOStreamMessageEventHandler" works. If the TCP/IP server device is still null (i.e., no connection to the server) it just simply closes the form. I just want a button instead of automatic connection to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite easy:

```
namespace Form1;

public partial class Main_Form: Form
{
    private CogJob Job;
    private CogJobManager Job_manager;
    private CogJobIndependent Job_independent;

    String Received_string;
    ICogIOTCPIP TCP_IP_server_device;
    
    public Main_HMI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Load application
        Job_manager = (CogJobManager)(CogSerializer.LoadObjectFromFile(@"Project"));

        // Initialize job variables
        Job = Job_manager.Job("Application");
        Job_independent = Job.OwnedIndependent;

        // Flush all job queues
        Job.ImageQueueFlush();
        Job_manager.UserQueueFlush();
        Job_manager.FailureQueueFlush();
        Job_independent.RealTimeQueueFlush();
    }
    
    // Decode the message received from the TCP/IP server device
    private void TCP_IP_server_device_MessageReceived(object sender, CogIOStreamMessageEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Received_string = eventArgs.DecodedMessage.Substring(2, 9);
    }

    // Savely shutdown application job manager when the form is closed;
    private void Main_HMI_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Job_manager.Shutdown();
    }

    private void Connect_to_TCP_IP_server_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Job_manager.IOEnable = true;
        TCP_IP_server_device = Job_manager.StreamInput("PLC", 2000, true);

        if (TCP_IP_server_device == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection failed", "TCP/IP server device connection status");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection successful", "TCP/IP server device connection status");
            TCP_IP_server_device.MessageReceived += new     CogIOStreamMessageEventHandler(TCP_IP_server_device_MessageReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Just enable event handling on successful connection.

Comment: I don't think it will work, since as far as I understand from your above solution I would have to click the "Connect to TCP/IP server button" everytime I send a message from the server side in order for my code to decode it. What I want is to only click the "Connect to TCP/IP server button" once and from then on it should start continiously listening to incomming messags from the server side, up until I disconnect from the server (disconnection I still need to code).

Comment: No, when you click the "connect" button, in the `else` statement (successful connection) the line `TCP_IP_server_device.MessageReceived += ...` means that you are subscribing to the `MessageReceived` event of the `TCP_IP_server_device` object.  So whenver the `MessageReceived` event is fired, the `TCP_IP_server_device_MessageReceived` function will be called without you pressing any buttons.